# get a dynamic sub array from JSON using java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to read json using java which contains data of a menu created by Jquery Plugin.

```
    [
  {
    "text": "Home",
    "href": "http://home.com",
    "icon": "fas fa-home",
    "target": "_top",
    "title": "My Home"
  },
  {
    "text": "Option1",
    "href": "",
    "icon": "fas fa-map-marker",
    "target": "_self",
    "title": "",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "Option1.1",
        "href": "",
        "icon": "fas fa-search",
        "target": "_self",
        "title": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "Option1.1.1",
            "href": "",
            "icon": "fas fa-plug",
            "target": "_self",
            "title": "",
            "children": [
              {
                "text": "Option1.1.1.1",
                "href": "",
                "icon": "fas fa-filter",
                "target": "_self",
                "title": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "Option1.2",
        "icon": "fab fa-amazon-pay",
        "href": "",
        "target": "_self",
        "title": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "Option1.2.1",
            "icon": "empty",
            "href": "",
            "target": "_self",
            "title": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "Option2",
    "icon": "fab fa-adversal",
    "href": "",
    "target": "_self",
    "title": ""
  }
]
```

Visual representation of this json will be like

[image]

Children array is created dynamically. It can be in every object. Is there a way to read the children array which is inside of other children arrays ?

I'm using json-simple to read the json file and my current code is :

```
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ryuuk\\Desktop\\data.json"));
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
        for (Iterator it = jsonArray.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) it.next();
            System.out.println(" <li><a href=\"#\">" + object.get("text") + "</a>");
            if (object.containsKey("children")) {
                System.out.println("<ul>");
                JSONArray achil = (JSONArray) object.get("children");
                for (int i = 0; i < achil.size(); i++) {
                    JSONObject objectx = (JSONObject) achil.get(i);
                    System.out.println(" <li><a href=\"#\">" + objectx.get("text") + "</a>");
                }
                System.out.println("</ul>");
            }
        }
```

Which will output this :

```
 <li><a href="#">Home</a>
 <li><a href="#">Option1</a>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Option1.1</a>
 <li><a href="#">Option1.2</a>
</ul>
 <li><a href="#">Option2</a>
```

[image]

How can I read those children arrays in **Option1.1.1** ?

Comment: Are you referring to this [`json-simple`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)?

Answer (score 0):

after few hours of trying i was able to comeup with a code that works

[image]

output

```
    <li>
   <a href="#">Programming</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">C++</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">C#</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Java</a> </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">Web Development</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">PHP</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Ruby</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Javascript</a> </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Python</a> </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#">OS</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Windows</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Macintosh</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Linux</a> </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#">Projects</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Android</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">iOS</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Web</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Windows</a> </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
```

jsp code

```
    <%
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ryuuk\\Desktop\\data.json"));
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
    out.write(new TagMaker().generateMenu(jsonArray));
%>
```

class -

```
    public class TagMaker {

    static String menuString = "";

    public String generateMenu(JSONArray obj) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
        for (Iterator it = jsonArray.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) it.next();
            menuString += " <li><a href=\"#\">" + object.get("text") + "</a>";
            if (checkforChildren(object.get("children"))) {
                looparray((JSONArray) object.get("children"));
            }
            menuString += " </li>";
        }
        System.out.println(menuString);
        return menuString;
    }

    public boolean checkforChildren(Object get) {
        return get != null;
    }

    public String looparray(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        menuString += "<ul>";
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject get = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            menuString += " <li><a href=\"#\">" + get.get("text") + "</a>";
            if (checkforChildren(get.get("children"))) {
                looparray((JSONArray) get.get("children"));
            }
            menuString += " </li>";
        }
        menuString += "</ul>";
        return menuString;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` for `menuString`, since string concatenation in a loop is bad practice (due to efficiency reasons - after each concatenation a new string is created, wasting both memory and time).